# How can I provide a service from another module?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

In my Module "Abrechnung" I want to use an tableadapter from the Module Stammdaten".

I tried to provide it to an controller in my Module.php (namespace Abrechnung):

```
        Controller\AbrechnungsimportController::class => function($container) {
            return new Controller\AbrechnungsimportController(
                $container->get(Model\AbrechnungsimportTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\AbrechnungTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\ImporttempTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\VertragshistorieTable::class),
                $container->get(Stammdaten\Model\VertragTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\Authentication::class)
                );
        },
```

The problem is with the provided VertragTable.

I get the following error message:

> Unable to resolve service "Abrechnung\Stammdaten\Model\VertragTable" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

So how can I use VertragTable in my Module "Abrechnung"?

EDIT:

I tried with the service-manager, but I no luck, probably lack of understanding

Then I provided the models in the Module.php like this:

```
Model\VertragTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(VertragTableGateway::class);
                return new AbrechnungModel\VertragTable($tableGateway);
            },

            VertragTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Abrechnung\Model\Vertrag());
                return new TableGateway('t_vertrag', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
```

Now I just copied the model and inputfilter in the new Module Abrechnung, of course it works but it is duplicate and I would prefer to use the already existing. If somebody could explain to me how to provide: Stammdaten\src\Model\VertragTable to the Module Abrechnung, It would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you have `VertragTable` configurated in your `module.config.php` file, e.g.: `'service_manager' => [ 'factories' => [ VertragTable::class => VertragTableFactory::class,],],`. You should then be able to do a simple `$container->get(VertragTable::class)` without any issues. (Obviously you'll have to create the Factory which needs to return a new instance of `VertragTable`, but judging by your code, you should have a few examples already, such as `AbrechnungTable(Factory)`)

Comment: I don't understand this, I think. you mean the application module.config.php? I added this one:     'service_manager' => [ 'factories' => [             Stammdaten\VertragTable::class => VertragTableFactory::class, ] ],  (VertarTable could not be resolved) What you suggested is different VertragTableFactory? I think I didn't get it.

Comment: No, I mean the `module.config.php` that you should have for the module you've got the `VertragTable::class` class in. That module should have a Factory for this class registered. The application uses `modules.config.php` (plural), but is also a level above the `module.config.php` files used by the different modules of an application. Example of what you might need [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-encrypt/blob/51aa4401bd2ef830b17792d8d14873681faa6b7f/config/module.config.php#L44)

Comment: Using a service from a different module works exactly the same as using a service from the same module. Have you defined a factory in the module.config.php of the Stammdaten module? Do you include the config file in the Module class of Stammdaten with the getConfig() action?